# Connect Linux machine to a windows active directory

Tags: linux, windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have a Linux machine which connected to an Active Directory on Windows server.
I configured the NIC to get an IP from the DHCP (from the windows server)

However, when I try to `nslookup <server IP>` on the Linux side it doesn't work (connection timeout), but on the same machine when I load windows and do `nslookup <server IP>` it works.

What can be wrong with my Linux configuration or Windows DNS configuration? 
note: I've configured my DNS to nonsecure and secure connections.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your DHCP box is giving out the proper DNS servers to DHCP clients. You can check /etc/resolv.conf on your linux box. If not, you can just set the dns server there manually 'nameserver x.x.x.x'; or fix DHCP to give the proper one.

Comment: it doesn't work for me